# Что не так с «подсесть к стене»

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов, семантика, глаголы

На другом сайте о русском языке [спросили](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/20994/8249), почему преподаватель пометил выделенную фразу как ошибочную:

> В зале стоял длинный стол с закусками, один из концов которого упирался в стену. Мы подошли к столу и стали за него садиться. **Я подсела к стене.**

Действительно, словари сообщают, что подсесть есть

> сесть рядом с кем-либо, чем-либо, около кого-либо, чего-либо

Даже приводят в пример:

> Засунув чугунок с картошкой в печь, она подсела к печи, сведённые простудой пальцы засовывала в самый огонь — грела.

В ответах говорят о том, что подсесть — это значит обязательно с целью дальнейшего взаимодействия.

Исчерпывающее ли это объяснение? Может, рассматриваемая фраза неудачна почему-то еще?

Answer (score 2):

Насчёт точности слова "взаимодействие": стена не обязана быть *интерактивной* и не бывает таковой. На мой взгляд, фраза "подсела к стене" не сама по себе ошибочна, а просто не подходит к контексту: речь идёт о том, кто где *сел*, поэтому ожидается *самодостаточный* глагол (сесть, усестья, расположиться и т. п.). Если к какому-то *объекту* (не *субъекту*, уже сидящему, - это другое) "подсаживаются", а из предшествуещего контекста неясно, для чего (**для какого дальнейшего действия**), то требуются последующие пояснения. Они возможны и в исходном примере (висевшее меню разглядеть, вилку в розетку воткнуть и т. п.). Но поскольку текст  *заканчивается* на "подсаживании", выбор слова воспринимается как *речевая ошибка* ("подсела к стене" в значении "садясь с друзьями за стол, выбрала место у стены" - неуместно), что и отметил преподаватель.

Answer (score 2):

Я тоже думаю, что это речевая ошибка - неверный выбор слова.  Подсесть - это присоединиться, приблизиться: подсесть к кому-либо, к столу, к компании, к компьютеру, за стол. Она села у стены, а не подсела к стене.

*В зале стоял длинный стол с закусками, один из концов которого упирался в стену. Мы подошли к столу и стали за него садиться. Я **подсела к стене**.* Получилось, что она подсела не к компании за столом, а к самой стене, стена - объект её внимания. Смысл получился не тот.

Можно было сказать: *В зале стоял длинный стол с закусками, один из концов которого упирался в стену. Мы подошли к столу и стали за него садиться. Я **подсела со стороны стены**.*

А лучше заменить слово *подсела*: *Мы подошли к столу и стали за него садиться. Я ***села у стены***.*

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу ошибку в другом. Ученица не смогла правильно выразить свою мысль. Она хотела сказать, что подсела к столу с той стороны, который упирался в стену. А получилось что-то другое.

Возможно, в каком-то контексте сказать "присесть к стене" будет допустимо, не уверен. Но даже если заменить сомнительную "стену" на вполне законную "печь", смысловая ошибка никуда не денется:

> В зале стоял длинный стол с закусками, один из концов которого
>   располагался у печи. Мы подошли к столу и стали за него садиться. Я
>   подсела к печи.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что желательно продолжение действия. Если он подсел к печи, то подразумевается для чего? Погреться. Если расширить действие здесь, например:
Он подсел к стене, достал дрель и начал сверлить дырку.
Вряд ли это вызвало бы неприятие.